# Is capturing on empty square with a pawn legal?

Tags: online-chess, computer-chess, en-passant

How is it possible to move c4 to b3?

[image: ...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of capturing with pawn called **capturing en passant**.

Here's the rule explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess#En_passant):

> When a pawn advances two squares from its starting position and there
>   is an opponent's pawn on an adjacent file next to its destination
>   square, then the opponent's pawn can capture it en passant (in
>   passing), and move to the square the pawn passed over. This can only
>   be done on the very next move, otherwise the right to do so is
>   forfeit.